# Function-try-block in a constructor: exception escapes

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, try-catch

I've heard function-try-block can be used on a normal function, a member function, a constructor and so on. I'd like to confirm this fact. But in using that with a constructor, I encounter a behavior I don't understand.

The code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void throws() {
    throw "Exception"; //throw an exception of string literal
}

class C {
    public:

        //constructor1
        C() try {
            throws();
        } catch (const char *) {
            cout << "Catched an exception.\n";
        } catch (...) {
            cout << "Unknown exception.\n";
        }

        //constructor2
//         C() {
//             try {
//                 throws();
//             } catch (const char *) {
//                 cout << "Catched an exception.\n";
//             } catch (...) {
//                 cout << "Unknown exception.\n";
//             }
//         }

};

int main() {

    C c; //=> "Catched an exception"
         //then error occurs
         //with a message "uncaught exception of type char const*"

}
```

- `constructor1`:

  In creating an object of class `C`, an exception is thrown via the function `throws()` and it is truly caught so that the message `"Catched an exception."` is output. However, the exception propagates and make the program terminated.
- `constructor2`:

  the message is output and the exception does not propagate.

Aren't `constructor1` and the `constructor2` grammatically the same?

Environment:

```
$ gcc --version

Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: In the case of Constructors the exception is implicitly rethrown if not rethrown by the catch block

Comment: @mkaes What do you mean? The second constructor(which is commented) is working fine.

Comment: Not sure if this is really a duplicate.

Comment: @Mohit In the first constructor exception interrupts constructor body so constructor itself fails, object is not constructed and exception is automatically rethrown. In the second constructor exception is caught *inside* of constructor body, so constructor itself exits normally and object is properly constructed.

Comment: @Mohit: I guess I was not precise enough. In case of Funtion-try-blocks on constructors the exception is rethrown. The second construtor has no function-try-block just a regular try catch. So for a plain function both would be the same but for Constructors those are different.

Comment: They are not "grammatically" the same, obviously. Your question should be: "semantically" the same?.

Comment: Thank you all. Now I understand the difference between the two constructor. The question which mine was marked as duplicate was also helpful.